# Build sitebricks with maven

Tags: maven, sitebricks

I'm stuck generating jars for Sitebricks with maven. I downloaded the repository from git with the following command:

git clone https://github.com/dhanji/sitebricks.git sitebricks

When using "mvn package" everything works fine. As I need the dependencies as well I tried "mvn install" and get the following error:

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Build Order:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Sitebricks :: Parent
[INFO] Sitebricks :: Type Conversion
[INFO] Sitebricks :: Client
[INFO] Sitebricks :: Annotations
[INFO] Sitebricks :: Core
[INFO] Sitebricks :: Test Support
[INFO] Sitebricks :: Easy Client
[INFO] Sitebricks :: Statistics
[INFO] Sitebricks :: Channel
[INFO] Sitebricks :: Acceptance Tests
[INFO] Sitebricks :: Options
[INFO] Sitebricks :: Cloud
[INFO] Sitebricks :: SLF4J Module
[INFO] Sitebricks :: Persistence
[INFO] Sitebricks :: Persistence Module (Disk)
[INFO] Sitebricks :: Persistence Module (Redis)
[INFO] Sitebricks :: Persistence Module (SQL)
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Sitebricks :: Parent 0.8.8-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.3:clean (default-clean) @ sitebricks-parent ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-enforcer-plugin:1.0-beta-1:enforce (enforce-maven) @ sitebricks-parent ---
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-install-plugin:2.3:install (default-install) @ sitebricks-parent ---
[INFO] Installing /home/dimi/local/sdks/maven/sitebricks/pom.xml to /home/dimi/.m2/repository/com/google/sitebricks/sitebricks-parent/0.8.8-SNAPSHOT/sitebricks-parent-0.8.8-SNAPSHOT.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary:
[INFO] 
[INFO] Sitebricks :: Parent .............................. FAILURE [2.880s]
[INFO] Sitebricks :: Type Conversion ..................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Sitebricks :: Client .............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Sitebricks :: Annotations ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Sitebricks :: Core ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Sitebricks :: Test Support ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Sitebricks :: Easy Client ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Sitebricks :: Statistics .......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Sitebricks :: Channel ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Sitebricks :: Acceptance Tests .................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Sitebricks :: Options ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] Sitebricks :: Cloud ............................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Sitebricks :: SLF4J Module ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] Sitebricks :: Persistence ......................... SKIPPED
[INFO] Sitebricks :: Persistence Module (Disk) ........... SKIPPED
[INFO] Sitebricks :: Persistence Module (Redis) .......... SKIPPED
[INFO] Sitebricks :: Persistence Module (SQL) ............ SKIPPED
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 4.226s
[INFO] Finished at: Wed Jan 09 20:57:48 CET 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/69M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-install-plugin:2.3:install (default-install) on project sitebricks-parent: Failed to install metadata com.google.sitebricks:sitebricks-parent/maven-metadata.xml: Could not parse metadata /home/dimi/.m2/repository/com/google/sitebricks/sitebricks-parent/maven-metadata-local.xml: only whitespace content allowed before start tag and not F (position: START_DOCUMENT seen F... @1:1) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

How can I fix that? I'm trying to get sitebricks going for some days now and beginning to become a litte frustrated...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try the answers on this thread:

https://github.com/dhanji/sitebricks/issues/51

What's happening is that your project is not configured properly with its own pom.xml, so you are missing a transitive dependency of Guice (aopalliance.jar) which is not defined anywhere explicitly (but which maven knows how to set up).

Im not sure how you generated the Eclipse project, but there is a flaw in that part of the puzzle =)

Dhanji
(creator of sitebricks)

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution is to delete the whole local repository and just rebuild or a little bit more specific you just delete the folder

```
/home/dimi/.m2/repository/com/google/sidebricks
```

and just do

```
mvn clean package
```

Comment: Thank you, This eliminated the errors when using maven, but I still get NoClassDefFoundErrors when trying to use sitebricks. As I'm a real maven noob I still think I might have done something wrong, generating the jars for sitebricks. In the pom.xml are lots of <dependency> items, but I can't find them in the generated jar. Is there a special command or something to include those dependencies?